# Getting a runtime 13 type mismatch error while working with array

Tags: excel, vba

So, I came across an issue with arrays in VBA not too long ago, that I was able to fix. However, I can't figure out why the fix worked, since logically what I did is telling VBA the exact same thing. None of the people in my office who code in VBA can answer this question.

The issue is that I want to take data from a table, store it in an array, and then copy it to another table. The code below works just fine for that, as it should since this is a simple task, so long as the table has at least 2 rows. If the table only has 1 row though, it spits out:

> runtime 13 type mismatch error

I commented the fix in the if statement below, so you can see what fixes it. If the table has one row of data, and say 1 column, then I'm redimming the array as `1,1` for size. This should match the table I want to copy the data to if it's also 1 row and 1 column. However, it won't let me just do `MyArray() = new table range`. I have to specifically tell it if there's 1 row then do `MyArray(nr, 1)`, which is the same thing to me, since the array is redimmed as nr, 1 anyway.

What am I missing here?

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub test()

Dim MyArray() As Variant
Dim nr As Integer

nr = Range("Tbl_Test[Data]").Rows.Count

ReDim MyArray(nr, 1)

MyArray() = Range("Tbl_Test[Data]")

    'If nr = 1 Then
        'MyArray(nr, 1) = Range("Tbl_Test[Data]")
    'Else:
        'MyArray() = Range("Tbl_Test[Data]")
    'End If

Range("Tbl_Test2[Data]") = MyArray()

End Sub
```

Comment: Try to erase "()" from MyArray in declaration and from setting the range of MyArray

Comment: See [this link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx), specifically about the special case of reading one cell into an array (about half-way down).

Comment: Thanks guys! That link helped understand arrays. The code didn't really help but taking () off MyArray allowed it to handle any data size including nr = 1. Much appreciated!